# Are my cats related?

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, strays

I adopted my first cat (Venus) 3 years ago, she showed up at a family barbecue in my backyard asking for food and we just took her in, she was an adult already and the vet said that she was probably 2 or 3 years old. A year ago I adopted my second, we found Nala in a box behind a building in my school, she was about 2 months old.

I live at a 10 minute walking distance from my school so they were both found nearby and they are identical. Everyone thinks Nala is Venus' daughter when they meet them. That is not the case, but is there a chance they could be somewhat related based on their looks and were we found them?

This is Venus on the back and Nala on the front:

[image: This is Venus on the back and Nala on the front.]

Comment: Really any answer would be pure conjecture.  You could only find out a reasonable answer through DNA testing, if DNA testing to determine whether animals are related is even available.  You should also keep in mind that type of marking on cats is largely determined by the conditions in the womb rather than genetics.  The gene for color is on the sex chromosome, so female cats can have two different color genes.  Which one ends up getting expressed where is affected by conditions of the womb.  A genetic clone of these cats would end up with a different pattern of markings.

Comment: it is unlikely that they are related but it is not impossible,a genetic test is the only way to be sure.

Comment: Related or not, they sure are pretty!